# how to detect model belongs to which plugin in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, model

How to detect in AppModel, model that is loaded, belong to which plug-in?

EDIT:

When I check model name or other details in AppModel, there is no difference between the model loaded from the main program and a model that within the plugin loaded.
I need to know if model belongs to the plugin to do some operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the name of your model being used by checking the Model::name property.  It gets set for you.

If that's not what you're after, please edit your question.  Your objective is a little unclear.